# Dynamic lines with plot as background

Tags: plotting, dynamic, interactive

I am trying to generate two lines (with 2 points each) that are dynamically updated with a plot as background.
I have come quite far, but do not manage to add the plot as background.

```
    initialLocations={{-5, 5}, {-1, 3},{-5,-1},{5,6}}

    DynamicModule[
    {p1=initialLocations[[1]],
    p2=initialLocations[[2]],
    p3=initialLocations[[3]],
    p4=initialLocations[[4]]},
    {
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[{p1,p2,p3,p4}],
    Dynamic[
    Graphics[{
    Red,Line[{p1,p2}],
    Blue,Line[{p3,p4}]},
    PlotRange->10,Axes->True,ImageSize->Medium]],
     Dynamic[{p1,p2,p3,p4}]
    }
                 ]
```

I would like to add a plot as background, such as:

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]
```

I tried to pack everything in "Show[]" but failed and also struggled to match the coordinate systems of the plot and the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
DynamicModule[
  {a1 = {1, 1}, a2 = {-1, -1}, b1 = {-1, 1}, b2 = {1, -1}},
  LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[{a1, a2, b1, b2}], 
    Dynamic[
      Show[
        Graphics[{Blue, Line[{a1, a2}], Red, Line[{b1, b2}]}],
        Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}]]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.